# H2 in memory OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY

Tags: sql-server, h2, in-memory-database

I am using H2 in memory db for my unit testing. To validate my results I am emulating H2 for Oracle and MSSQL Server. I am generating following SQL statement which fails;

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Query failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM "data" ORDER BY "integer" OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT * FROM ""data"" ORDER BY ""integer"" OFFSET[*] 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM "data" ORDER BY "integer" OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2 ROWS ONLY [42000-176]
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
    at com.temenos.interaction.jdbc.producer.TestOrderByTop.testOrderedQuery(TestOrderByTop.java:110)
    at com.temenos.interaction.jdbc.producer.TestOrderByTop.testAscQueryMSSQL(TestOrderByTop.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

But when I run the same query from H2 Console it works absolutely fine. Am I missing anything? Or H2 in memory does not support these emulations?

Comment: Another good example why it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for testing than in production.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name something is better then NOTHING! Just to update the problem was the H2 driver used in my project pom was 1.3.X where FETCH is supported from 1.4.x. I updated my driver and everything works as expected